# How do I center my right borders in my navigation?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to center my right borders in between my navigation links
(Especially for when the browser is resizing). I can center it with padding but when I resize the browser the border it will not stay centered.

[image]

HTML

```
  <header>
    <img class="pebble-beach-golf-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="tree on a cliff with '1919' written underneath">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">The Course</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rates & Memberships</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tee Times</a></li>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

SASS

```
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  li {
    font-family: $primary-font;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 1em;
    border-right: double $primary-color;
  }
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    &:visited {
      color: inherit;
    }
    &:hover {
      @include hover
    }
    &:active {
      color: $primary-color;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One way might be: ```li { padding-right: 10px; }``` the amount may change according to other parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `flex: 1;` to have each `<li>` fill as much space as possible (distributed equally). Then you can center each `<a>` in the `<li>`s and apply the border to the `<li>`s.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
}

li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: double black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">The Course</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rates & Memberships</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tee Times</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, where whole list has content centered with 10px padding on li items:

```css
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
li {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1em;
  border-right: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /*...*/
}
li:last-child {
   border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img class="pebble-beach-golf-logo" src="images/logo.png" alt="Tree">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">The Course</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Rates & Memberships</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Tee Times</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: The ```li { display: flex;
    justify-content: center;} is redundant?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to remove it while testing. Updated